# How can you create a pop-up window in Discord that accepts an input from the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

It's my first time seeing this feature from a Discord bot. I tried looking everywhere but it seems that I have failed. There's this feature from Captcha.bot Discord bot where you can accept input from a pop-up window inside Discord.

There's a button in an embedded message made by Captcha.bot where you will have to answer a Captcha test. After pressing the button, it creates a pop-up window like this.

[image]

After placing the right answer on the captcha bot, here's the aftermath of the experience.

[image]

All I want to learn is how to summon that pop-up window using Discord.js if it's even possible or at least learn how they did it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are called modals, and they will be available in the next major discord.js version, v14. There is already a [pull request](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/7023) for this.

### Update 2022-07-19: Modals in v14.0.0

There are some changes in v14. If you try to update your code from v13.7, there are a few differences:

- `Modal` is now `ModalBuilder`
- `MessageActionRow` is now `ActionRowBuilder`
- `TextInputComponent` is now `TextInputBuilder`
- you need to use enums like `TextInputStyle.Short`, `ButtonStyle.Primary`, etc. instead of strings (i.e. `"SHORT"`, or `"PRIMARY"`)
- `interaction` no longer has a `isModalSubmit` type guard. You'll need to check its `type` against the `InteractionType.ModalSubmit` enum

You can find the full code below that you can use with discord.js v14:

```js
// discord.js version v14.0.0+
const {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
  Client,
  Events,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  InteractionType,
  ModalBuilder,
  TextInputBuilder,
  TextInputStyle,
} = require('discord.js');

const TOKEN = 'YOUR TOKEN HERE';
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ],
});

client.on(Events.MessageCreate, (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  let button = new ActionRowBuilder();
  button.addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('verification-button')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
      .setLabel('Open modal dialog'),
  );
  message.reply({
    components: [button],
  });
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'verification-button') {
      const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('verification-modal')
        .setTitle('Verify yourself')
        .addComponents([
          new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new TextInputBuilder()
              .setCustomId('verification-input')
              .setLabel('Answer')
              .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
              .setMinLength(4)
              .setMaxLength(12)
              .setPlaceholder('ABCDEF')
              .setRequired(true),
          ),
        ]);

      await interaction.showModal(modal);
    }
  }

  if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ModalSubmit) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'verification-modal') {
      const response =
        interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
      interaction.reply(`Yay, your answer is submitted: "${response}"`);
    }
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot v14 is connected...');
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

[image]

### Previous answer 2022-06-28: Modals in v13.7.0

Modals are available since [v13.7.0](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/13.7.0). If you try to update your code from `discord-modals`, there are a few differences:

- you'll need to import `Modal` and `TextInputComponent` from discord.js
- `TextInputComponent`s must be inside a `MessageActionRow`s
- the `interaction` has a `showModal()` method that opens the modal
- the `interaction` has an `isModalSubmit()` method that checks if it's a `ModalSubmitInteraction`
- there is no `modalSubmit` event
- to get the response you need to use `interaction.fields.getTextInputValue()`

You can find the full code below that you can use in v13.7:

```js
// discord.js version v13.7.0+
const {
  Client,
  Intents,
  MessageActionRow,
  MessageButton,
  Modal,
  TextInputComponent,
} = require('discord.js');

const TOKEN = 'YOUR TOKEN HERE';
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  let button = new MessageActionRow();
  button.addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId('verification-button')
      .setStyle('PRIMARY')
      .setLabel('Open modal dialog'),
  );
  message.reply({
    components: [button],
  });
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'verification-button') {
      const modal = new Modal()
        .setCustomId('verification-modal')
        .setTitle('Verify yourself')
        .addComponents([
          new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
            new TextInputComponent()
              .setCustomId('verification-input')
              .setLabel('Answer')
              .setStyle('SHORT')
              .setMinLength(4)
              .setMaxLength(12)
              .setPlaceholder('ABCDEF')
              .setRequired(true),
          ),
        ]);

      await interaction.showModal(modal);
    }
  }

  if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'verification-modal') {
      const response =
        interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
      interaction.reply(`Yay, your answer is submitted: "${response}"`);
    }
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot v13 is connected...');
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

### First answer 2022-03-30: Using the `discord-modals` package

In the meantime, you can use an npm package like [discord-modals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-modals) or [discordjs-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discordjs-modal).

You can find a working example with the `discord-modals` package below. Don't forget to install it first using `npm i discord-modals`.

```js
// discord-modals
const {
  Client,
  Intents,
  MessageActionRow,
  MessageButton,
} = require('discord.js');
const discordModals = require('discord-modals');
const { Modal, TextInputComponent, showModal } = discordModals;

const TOKEN = 'YOUR TOKEN HERE';
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
discordModals(client);

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  let button = new MessageActionRow();
  button.addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId('verification-button')
      .setStyle('PRIMARY')
      .setLabel('Open modal dialog'),
  );
  message.reply({
    components: [button],
  });
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'verification-button') {
      const modal = new Modal() // We create a Modal
        .setCustomId('verification-modal')
        .setTitle('Verify yourself')
        .addComponents([
          new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('verification-input')
            .setLabel('Answer')
            .setStyle('SHORT')
            .setMinLength(4)
            .setMaxLength(12)
            .setPlaceholder('ABCDEF')
            .setRequired(true),
        ]);

      showModal(modal, {
        client,
        interaction,
      });
    }
  }
});

client.on('modalSubmit', async (modal) => {
  if (modal.customId === 'verification-modal') {
    const response = modal.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
    modal.reply(`Yay, your answer is submitted: "${response}"`);
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot v13 is connected...');
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Just curious, where are the answer going to?

Comment: Nowhere, it's just sitting in a variable (`response`) inside the `modalSubmit` event's callback.

Comment: You cause use this too for any collection events?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _any collection events_, sorry

Comment: [Something like this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions)

Comment: Is there something I can do in python to get the same result

Comment: @ArshpreetSingh I'm pretty sure you can find some tutorials online, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxcSt9Ip63w